# Python: Access/Save memory block just given by pointer without copying

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

Here is an example of what I try to do:

```
import ctypes
MEM_SIZE = 1024*1024*128

# allocate memory (this is Windows specific)
ptr = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.malloc(MEM_SIZE)

# make memory accessible to Python calls
mem = ctypes.string_at(ptr, MEM_SIZE)
# BAD: string_at duplicates memory

# store it to disk
open(r'test.raw', 'wb').write(mem)
```

In a nutshell: I have a plain memory pointer, I know the size of the block and want to store it on disk or reuse it as a numpy array.

How can I do that without generating a copy of the memory block?

---

Related question: [stackoverflow: Fill python ctypes pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730841/fill-python-ctypes-pointer) (thanks to Brian Larsen for the hint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_char * MEM_SIZE).from_address(ptr)
with open('test.raw', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ctypes_array)

numpy_array = numpy.frombuffer(ctypes_array, dtype=numpy.byte)
numpy_array.tofile('test.raw')
```

Comment: Great, your suggestion works w/o copying the data! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you just want to store it and don't need the numpy array, you can do that with:

open('test.raw', 'wb').write(ctypes_array)

Comment: @TomPohl OK, added that to my answer.