# Fill python ctypes pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C function `uint8_t *begin();` which returns a pointer to allocated memory.

Here is a `ctypes` binding to it:

```
begin = mylibrary.begin
begin.argtypes = ()
begin.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8)
```

I need to fill memory with an array of the integers. Is there any quicker way to do it instead of this?

```
buffer = begin()
data = range(10)
for idx, value in enumerate(data):
    buffer[idx] = ctypes.c_uint8(value)
```

It doesn't look to me, that iterating over the whole array is a very fast method, because that iterable data can contains a lot of items, millions of integers or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add dependencies, [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html) makes this easier.

Here is an example I put together.

The C (note the length is set to 10)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int *begin(void) {
    return calloc(10, sizeof(int));
}
```

and the python

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
# make the data I want to put into C
data = np.arange(10, dtype=ctypes.c_int)
# setup the ctypes just as you did
mylibrary = ctypes.CDLL('a.out')
begin = mylibrary.begin
begin.argtypes = ()
begin.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
# and do the same memmove that Kirill suggested
ctypes.memmove(buffer, data.ctypes.get_data(), ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)*len(data))
# and print some out
print buffer[2]
# 2
```

If you are clever with numpy you can do multidimensional arrays this way too.

One needs to think a bit on who owns the memory and how to clear it out and not segfault (or leak) anywhere as you are getting close the the underlying C.  For example `del buffer` will not free the created buffer, that has to be done in C.

Answer (score 1):

Python list has corresponding [C type](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html) which I guess has internal C array of [PyObject](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyObject)'s.  Consequently, you have to iterate over list items in order to convert them to `int`'s anyway.  There is may be some trick way to write it in one line but I think the simpler the better.

P.S. Consider using [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> from array import array
>>> TenInts = ctypes.c_int * 10
>>> arr = array('i', range(10))
>>> carr = TenInts()
>>> arr_addr, arr_len = arr.buffer_info()[0], len(arr) * arr.itemsize
>>> ctypes.memmove(carr, arr_addr, arr_len)
13893440
>>> print '; '.join(map(str, carr))
0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9
```